# Cannot summarize the qty in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I currently make a query DB to summary the Qty based on ShipNo, but it could not be summarized- due to the different date are exists. I have tried to convert the date  format using yyyy-mm-dd but It does not solve it. Did I miss something ?

Here is the code that I used.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  T1.ShipNo
            ,    CONVERT(VARCHAR,T1.EndDt,23) EndDt
            ,    SUM(T2.ShipQty) AS ShipQty 
FROM WNTPRD.ASSY_2022.dbo.T_MetalShip AS T1
INNER JOIN WNTPRD.ASSY_2022.dbo.T_MetalShip_Lot AS T2 ON T1.MetalShipID = T2.MetalShipID
WHERE 0=0
AND T1.ShipNo = 'TIC1P03Q00010'
GROUP BY T1.ShipNo, T1.EndDt
```

And here is the result of the query above;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUWs3.png)

Comment: Converting the date in the column selection will not have any effect on how your data is grouped or sumed. You need to convert the date also in your group by clause. If you need further assistance, please provide some sample data.

Comment: @JonasMetzler : Thank you very much for your help, It works and I already fix it. Once again thank you